# Escape single and double quote in attributes shows error on Wordpress only

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
$height.prop('placeholder', '(e.g., 5\' or 5\'5" or 5\'5)');
```

Im trying to set my placeholder using JQuery prop method,  but I got this error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

I have working fiddle [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bu676dft/1/) but when I put it on my wordpress site, I got the error above.

Comment: Do you have other query? Since the above code is working perfectly in my testing environment. I think your syntax is wrong in another JS code probably.

Answer (score 0):

Try nesting the single quotes inside double quotes instead of using escape characters.